# Stop Excel from guessing cell-formats

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column like this:

```
000123-1234
000123-1234
000123-1234
012345-5678
123456-1234
234567-2345
345678-3456
```

And I need to remove the dash. If I just mark that column and do a search-replace, then Excel thinks: 'Yeah, alright - now this must be a number. And number has no prefixed zero's; so I better remove them'. 
   But no! I need the zero's!

I've tried formatting the cells as text, as 'standard' and as a number - but without luck.

How can I stop Excel from trying to help me out - and just do what I tell it to do **and only that!?**

I know that I can make two new columns where I first get the first 6 chars, - and then get the last 4 chars and then merge them together... But is that really the best way to do this!?

Comment: Setting cells' number format as "text" should work. How exactly you've tried it? (You need to change format BEFORE removing `-`)

Comment: @MátéJuhász even after setting the cells as text before using Replace, it returns a text but it truncates the leading `0`s.  At least it does for me.

Comment: Yup. It should, - shouldn't it!? ... I mark the cells, press `CMD`+`1` - choose `text` and press `ok`. I mean... How can I mess that up?

Comment: You can use a helper column with: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")` which returns a string.

Comment: Strange indeed, it seems applying number format before actually checking cell format:(

Comment: have a look on this [add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php). I've tried and with that you can remove only `-` and keep leading zeros (if format of cells is already text).

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be known behavior in Excel.

You can use a macro to preserve the Text formatting and perform a find/replace. Use the following subroutine:

```
Sub RemoveHyphen(RangeString As String)

For Each Cell In Range(RangeString)
    Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
    Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "-", "")
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Call the subroutine with `RemoveHyphen("A1:A7")` in the VBA immediate window. It will format all cells as text and remove the hypens.

Comment: If you already write a macro, why not include changing number format too? That could save one step.

Comment: I edited the macro to include setting the cell format to Text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom format to show the leading zeros:

[image: Screenshot of number format]

Enter as many `0`'s as there are digits in your numbers.

Comment: Interesting...it does appear that Excel retains custom formatting even after performing a find/replace

Comment: Could someone with enough rep polease edit this answer to put the screenshot inline? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, @davidmneedham.  Maybe I could have done that? Still learning the ropes.

Comment: A reputation score of 10 is required to post inline images, so you can now do it.

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")
```

and copy downward.  Then copy column **B** and `PasteSpecialValues` back onto column **A**.  Any leading zeros will be preserved!